# How large is the set, that is generated by an unrestricted number of operations on elements of $F$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Given $F$, a set of functions of one unknown $x$:
$$
F=\{c,x, \exp(x),\ln(x) \},
$$
where $c$ is a constant term.
Further, given the following operations on functions:

1. Addition $f+g$
2. Multiplication $f\cdot g$
3. Divison $f/g$
4. Composition $f\circ g$

How large is the set, that is generated by an unrestricted number of operations on elements of $F$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its cardinality is $\aleph_0$.

To see this, notice that the set in question is $\bigcup_n F_n$ where $F_0$ is the set you started with and $F_{n+1}$ is $F_n$ plus the results of each of these operations on any valid pair of elements of $F_n$. Clearly $F_{n+1}$ has cardinality no greater than $\lvert F_n\rvert+\aleph_0$ (because there are no more pairs of elements of $F_n$).

On the other hand, natural multiples of $e^x$ alone are infinite in number.